# getting all or last email attachment python

Tags: python, email, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to get either all attachments from my email given a specific title of the email, or get the last email with a specific title *and* attachment

I have the following so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime as date
import time
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
val_date = date.date.today()

sub_today = 'GG in GD'

for item in messages:
    if item.Subject == sub_today:
        print(item.Subject)
        print(item.SentOn)
        attachments = item.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        attachment.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment))
        Good_Data = pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment))
```

Because the next part of this script requires me to be running this on 2.7, I'm not sure how to fix this code to get what I need. in 3.6 I can do this:

```
for item in messages:
    if item.Subject == sub_today and item.SentOn.date() == val_date:
```

Ideally I would like to get a list of all of those attachments for the past few days and grab the most recent one with an attachment, and maybe the date.

I've been running into issues using the `item.SentOn` which is type `time`. I've tried to convert it to string and then `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, or subtract something from `time.time()` and try to see if its greater than. But I haven't had any success.

Even when I try to convert the `time` object to `datetime` it gets all messed up.

```
message.SentOn
<PyTime:3/7/2018 10:18:03 AM>

date.date.fromtimestamp(message.SentOn)
datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
```

I would like to have it do something like:

```
for item in messages:
    if item.Subject == sub_today and item.SentOn > time.time.today()-2weeks and item.Attachments is not null:
        attachments = item.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        att.append(attachment)
        attachment.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment))
        Good_Data = pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment))
```

Comment: Surely, this question has nothing to do with emails or attachments. Can't you explain the *core* issue you are trying to solve instead?

Comment: If there is a better way to pull these, then yes it does have to do with attachments given that one possible solution would be to add an argument in the for loop that checks for attachment on each email I'm iterating through. The _core_ issue I'm trying to solve is using the for loop to pull attachments out of recent emails, and take the latest one. `if item.Subject == sub_today and item.SentOn > time.time.today()- 2 weeks and item.Attachments is not null` I'm tripped up on filtering SentOn date, and checking that there is an attachment

Comment: edited to add what I'm looking for it to do.

Comment: Again, your issue has **nothing** to do with outlook or emails or attachments. You appear to be having difficulty iterating over a COM container using Python 2.x. An answer to that question can be used to enumerate anything from USB devices to items in an Outlook folder. The issue itself is unrelated to the application.